# How would you say "What do you reach with hate and staying angry" in old latin writing?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin

I would like to translate correctly the sentence "what do you reach with hate and staying angry". I would like this in old latin writing if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I assume by "reach" you mean "achieve."

I'm unsure what you mean by "old Latin writing," especially since this question was also tagged "classical-latin." [Latin cursive?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_cursive)

Anyway, here is a more or less classical suggestion:

> Odio quid consequere, quid in ira perseverando?

This would literally be: "What do you achieve through hate, what by persisting in anger?" Another option would be *... in ira haerendo*, "by clinging/holding on to your anger," perhaps a slightly different nuance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! You are quite right, it should have been Old Latin cursive, which contradicts the tag classical-Latin. 

But your sense of "What do you achieve through hate, what by persisting in anger?" is exactly what I was looking for. Really thank you!

Comment: @AxelKok no contradiction at all, because the so-called "Old Cursive" was used throughout the classical era as the primary form of handwriting (including all those graffiti in Pompeii). Unfortunately, I'm not particularly proficient in it.

Comment: For an Old Latin version of Article 1 of the UN bill of human rights with a transcription and Classical Latin equivalent, you might be interested to see:-  https://omniglot.com/writing/latin.htm.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this from Seneca Minor:

> Deinde quid opus est ira, cum idem proficiat ratio? (Of what use, further, is anger, when the same end may be accomphlished by reason?; Loeb Translation)

We can do some modifications here to match what we are seeking. I would suggest

> Quid opus est odio? et quid proficit ira [tua]? (What use is of hate, and what [your] anger achieves?)